# Single HTTP provider or Multiple HTTP provider in jboss-esb.xml

Tags: esb, jboss-esb

I am having 6 services in jboss-esb.xml file. At present iam using only one HTTP provider which is having BUSID.

I am using the same BUSIDREF for all the 6 six services and its working fine for me.

But my question is will it make any problem once if my ESB component gets coupled with other components like CRM or B2B.

Should I keep different BUSID's or is it ok to Have single BUSID for Several services.

I also want to know the performance impact on ESB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The esb will work fine if you have single bus id for different services but when it comes to performance issue it will get effected.

If you have a different bus id's then each service is independent on of other services which again increase the performance level of esb.